# How much is the acceptable percentage for Random Forest in Landslides prediction?

Tags: prediction, overfitting, random-forests

RF had been developed to overcome overfitting in decision trees but in some cases RF still experiences overfitting in landslide prediction, which varies from 2% to 12%. How much overfitting is acceptable? and how much datasets is considered good enough to use RF. it was said that the sample size should be 20 times greater than the variables in order to use RF but still sometimes RF have a bad prediction compared to logistic regressionin certain cases even though the sample size meets the criteria.I hope somebody can enlighten me with this issue.